# Laravel - Error in permissions with two sites on the same server

Tags: laravel, permissions

I have two laravel sites on the same server, I use laratrust. When I log in to both sites with the same access data the passwords get mixed between the two sites.

If I log in to site A, I lose the permissions, if I log in last at site B I lose in A. The problem is kept using different browsers, so it's a server / laravel problem

Answer (score 0):

add your domain name in domain section of app/session.php

```
'domain' => 'example.com',
```